# How to configure Nginx with multiple proxies

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm using port `3000` for Node, `8899` for WebSockets, and `3000/graphql`.

Based on a configuration I have for another application, I have the following:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/domain-name.com/public_html/some_folder/dist/;

    index index.html;

    server_name domain-name.com www.domain-name.com;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/domain-name.com.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/domain-name.com.error.log;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name domain-name.com www.domain-name.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8899;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name domain-name.com www.domain-name.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name domain-name.com www.domain-name.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/graphql;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

I've tried stripping the `location` blocks down to the basic `proxy_pass` but nothing after the first `server` block works.

I've tried swapping the ports, such as `listen 80` for `listen 3000` in their corresponding blocks, but I get an error: "Port already in use."

Recommendations welcome!

Comment: You need to use single `server` block with multiple `location` blocks each using it's own proxy, something like `location / { try_files ... } location /api/ { proxy_pass <proxy1> } location /graphql/ { proxy_pass <proxy2> }`. See [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html#simple_php_site_configuration) document for the location selection algorithm.

Comment: I don't understand how I would make that work within the application itself, as the environmental variables are referencing the actual port numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add corresponding 'A' records for the Hosted Zone in Route 53, and then make the appropriate changes to the configuration, and the environmental variables for the deployment target:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name sockets.domain-name.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8899;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name api.domain-name.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name graphql.domain-name.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/graphql;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```